# How can I rearrange and update a sequence of number in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my table, each row can hold an integer let's call this integer column `height`.
for example, the values in this column could be: `[5, 4, 0, 1, 9]`
I need for this sequence in the example to be rearranged to become: `[0, 1, 4, 5, 9]` and then I want these values to become like this: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

The idea I am trying to write in SQL is to get the minimum at the first time and count how many values are there less than it.

How can I write/translate this idea into an SQL Query?

Comment: whether values in column `height` can be duplicate. or your table is having any primary key field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a ranking:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (order by height) as height_seqnum
from t
order by height_seqnum;
```

Comment: Yes but at the same time I need to replace the height value by its ranking. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Can I associate the UPDATE clause to the query that you have written?

Comment: @MahSou . . . Assuming you have a primary key on the table (or that height is unique), then yes.  Just use this as a subquery in an `update`.